# Refer to static resource name dynamicly in Salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to loop article categories and provide an icon image for each of categories depending on its title in Salesforce Apex. I don't want to hard code each static resource name. My idea is to create a string variable for each loop iteration and refer to matching static resource name by this variable value. So I had a look at the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_resource.htm) on this matter, and it doesn't seem to work the way it's expected.

```
<knowledge:categoryList categoryVar="category" categoryGroup="Help" rootCategory="Using_{!selectedCategory}" level="1">
    <apex:variable var="iconSource" value="pkb_{!selectedCategory}_{!category.name}" />
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <div class="box-title">
            <h3>{!category.label}</h3>
        </div>
        <apex:image value="{!$Resource[iconSource]}" />
    </a>
</knowledge:categoryList>
```

Any thoughts how it's usually done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Static resource with inner structure like:

```
/js/...
/css/...
/img/...
```

You can access to static resource items using such construction:

```
{!URLFOR($Resource.resourceName, 'img/imageName.jpg')}
```

So, for apex:image tag it will look like:

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.resourceName, 'img/imageName.jpg')}" width="50" height="50"/>
```

Comment: do you mean I need to upload a `.zip` static resource and refer to it's inner structure using my `iconSource` variable?

Comment: Yes, it's usual approach for such cases in Salesforce. You can find more info in SF documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources.htm

Comment: Well, you know, the logics is working fine, but it's adding extra `orgId` param in the end of my url, so I get 404 back... 'GET http://blablabla.force.com/resource/1467725336000/pkb_category_icons/Classic/Basics.svg?orgId=00D400000008JQP 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: but I'm just refering to it as `<apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pkb_category_icons, '/Classic/Basics.svg')}"/>`

Comment: It can be related to cache control field value in Static resource.

Comment: Nope... changed from public to private, private to public... same result :(

Comment: I just checked '<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.resourceName, 'img/imageName.jpg')}"/>' with my test Static resource and public cache control - all works fine. Are you authorized on this SF sandbox or maybe you try to get access to this resource without authorization?

Comment: I have dev permissions. Is that what you mean? I'm first time doing SF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116480/discussion-between-last-khajiit-and-markoffden).